# How to extend Ember.String without prototype?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just tried `reopenClass()` and `extend()` but I was a bit surprised to see `Em.String` insist it didnt have those functions.

I also tried `reopen()` but that failed in the same way.

I don't want to use prototype if I don't have to, as I want to keep within the *Ember way*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ember.String` is just a hash with a couple of utility functions see here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.4/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/string.js#L24. Ember extends the `String.prototype` adding those utility functions.

I guess you have no other way than extending the vanilla `String.prototype` for additionally functionality you may need that is not provided by ember, your functions will then live alongside with ember's.

> Note taken from the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html):
>   Defines string helper methods including string formatting and localization. Unless Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES.String is false these methods will also be added to the String.prototype as well.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Ember extends `String.prototype` here as of the latest commit at this moment - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/632191f09770113cdc84ffd6e080315ab57c3f65/packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/string.js#L21

All the functions that are inserted into `String.prototype` are hardcoded in there, so adding anything to `Ember.String` will *not* be added to `String.prototype` by Ember.js, so the only way is to add methods to strings yourself directly.